# Restrict Spring page view into POST only

Tags: java, spring, view, controller, http-status-code-405

My Spring controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "calc")
public class CalcController {

  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showCalcPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

      // assemble page

    return "calc";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String showResultsPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      BindingResult result, Model model,
      final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
      HttpServletRequest request) {

    myService.evaluate(myModel);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("myModel", myModel);
    model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);

    return "redirect:calc/results";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/results")
  public String showResultsPage(ModelMap model,
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") final MyModel myModel,
      final BindingResult bindingResult) {

    // assemble page

    return "results";
  }
}
```

I have a mapping of the URL `calc` with both GET and POST and another for `calc/results`.

This works perfectly for me but whenever I try to access `calc/results` directly, the page still renders.

Hence I did a POST restriction to its `RequestMethod` like:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String showResultsPage(ModelMap model,
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") final MyModel myModel,
      final BindingResult bindingResult) {

    // assemble page

    return "results";
  }
```

This eliminated the direct viewing of the mapping by throwing a `405` but when I submit my form from `calc`, the error still persists.

**How do I merge these two situations that I have?**

I actually just want two controllers like the one below to implement POST and page restriction but it's not working in my part (I diagnosed it to the different mapping of `jsp`).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "calc")
public class CalcController {

  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showCalcPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

      // assemble page

    return "calc";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String showResultsPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      BindingResult result, Model model,
      final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
      HttpServletRequest request) {

    // assemble page    

    myService.evaluate(myModel);
    model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);

    return "redirect:results";
  }
}
```

Comment: In your form you should mention the method as `POST`.

Comment: @TejaKantamneni, yes my jsp form has a `method="POST"` attribute in it plus an `action="calc"` to map to my controllers.

Comment: action should be `calc/results`, correct? If it is, it should work, try looking at http exchange using firbug and see what the issue is

Comment: It now throws an `HTTP 500`.

Comment: That could be a different issue. A possible application exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally implemented both `POST` restriction and successful viewing of the `calc/results` page (but without `redirect` since it causes a "redirect loop" according to my Tomcat server).

Here is the final controller:

```
@Controller
public class CalcController {

  protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "calc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showCalcPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    // assemble page

    return "calc";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "calc/results")
  public String showResultsPage(
      @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
      ModelMap model, final BindingResult bindingResult,
      HttpServletRequest request) {

    // assemble page

    // apply BindingResult validation in da fyoochoor
    myService.evaluate(myModel);
    model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);

    return "results";
  }
}
```

Visiting `calc/results` directly now throws an `HTTP 500` and that will keep it secured. Just make sure to declare a page for this exception in your `web.xml` for aesthetics upon deployment.

Comment: visiting `calc/results` directly should throw a `405` method not allowed not `500`.

Comment: Thank you. Is it wrong to leave it at `500` and not `405`? I'll continue to fix it though.